# Why am I getting "arithmetic of pointer type is required"?

Tags: c, pointers, casting, struct

In the following code, I get an error when I typecast the float pointer to a struct, but the compiler does not complain if I typecast to something else. Why is it doing this?

```
typedef unsigned byte CELbool;
typedef struct {(...)} Color;
typedef struct {
    (...)
    Color color;
    CELbool b;
} Light;

Light _light;

void function(float *x) {
    _light.b = (CELbool)*x; // No error
    _light.color = (Color)*x; // (!) Used type 'Color' where arithmetic or pointer type is required
}
```

**Edit**: So say that I have a *x is a pointer to a Color, then what would be the proper way to get that Color? I am currently using `Color c = *((Color *)(value))`, but I don't think that that is the correct way to do it.

Comment: You're not casting the float *pointer* to anything; you're casting `*x`, the referent of the pointer, which has type `float`.

Comment: You're trying to cast a float to a struct...

Comment: @EdS.: I was getting the same error for different things I tried, so I did not initially realize this. I was trying to cast the pointer to a Color pointer and then dereference it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The conversions you are doing are not conversions from pointers into integers or structs, but conversions from floats to integers and structs.  The expression

```
(CELbool)*x
```

casts the value of `*x` (which, since `x` is a `float*`, is a `float`) into a `CELBool`, which you've defined as a typedef for some integral type.  This conversion is okay, as C allows for conversions between floating-point and integral values, since there is a reasonable way of doing the conversion.  However, the second cast is

```
(Color)*x
```

`Color` is a struct, and C does not define conversions between floating-point types and `struct`s, just as it doesn't define conversions between integral types and `struct`s, since in general there is no reasonable way to do this conversion.

The reason for the error about "pointer or arithmetic type required" is because the cast from the `float` would need to be to some type that `float`s can be converted to, which would be either some real-valued type, an integral type, or a pointer type, since `float`s can be converted to pointers (though it's a really bad idea to do so!)  The type `Color` isn't expected by the compiler's list of reasonable things to put there, hence the error.

Hope this helps!

Comment: So say that I have a *x is a pointer to a Color, then what would be the proper way to get that Color? I am currently using *((Color *)(value)), but I don't think that that is the correct way to do it.

Comment: If `x` really is a pointer to a `Color`, then `*(Color *)x` would be the way to get it; this says "convert `x` to a pointer to a `Color`, then dereference it."  That said, why is `x` really pointing at a `Color` if the parameter is a `float*`?  That seems worrisome.

Comment: `float *value` is the same as `float value[]`, and Color is three floats(r,g,b), which simplifies to `float value[3]`. My method would actually set various things depending on another parameter. I should probably use void*, but the most common input should be a float.